# ProgressDialog in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have a procedure that extracts data from a database and populates it to the list. I want to display progress dialog box while query is executed, but it visually appears only after the query is executed. I believe I have to run a `ProgressDialog` in a separate thread, but followed few suggestions and could not make it work.

So in my `Activity` I just have

```
private void DisplayAllproductListView(String SqlStatement) {           
     ProgressDialog dialog = 
     ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.context, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
     //..................
     //..................
     //execute sql query here
     dialog.dismiss();
   }
```

thanks

Comment: sepearate thread!. use asynctask display progress dialog in `onPreExecute` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Try using an AsyncTask

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.show your process dialog in main thread

2.start a new thread (such as Thread A) to process your heavy job

3.when done, use handler to send a message from Thread A to main thread, the latter dismisses the process dialog

code like this
    private ProcessDialog pd;

```
private void startDialog()
{

 pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "title", "loading");  

     //start a new thread to process job
     new Thread(new Runnable() {  
         @Override  
         public void run() {  
             //heavy job here
             //send message to main thread
             handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); 
          }  
      }).start(); 
}

Handler handler = new Handler() {  
    @Override  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pd.dismiss(); 
    }  
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I think it is perfectly working except it crashes for me. The thing is that my "heavy job" includes query , customised data adaptor and mapping to list view. Do you think it could be the problem?? should I have query only in a new tread??

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
private class MyAwesomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Create progress dialog here and show it
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Execute query here

        return null;

    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //update your listView adapter here
        //Dismiss your dialog

    }

}
```

To call it:

```
new MyAwesomeAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I think it is perfectly working except it crashes for me. The thing is that my "heavy job" includes query , customised data adaptor and mapping to list view. Do you think it could be the problem?? should I have query only in a async task??

Comment: try to put the code of the adapter and listview update in the onPostExecute method. You can't manipulate the UI thread from the doInBackground method, as it runs in background :)

Comment: Thanks again. query and prepare of custom list is working finest in doInBackground. how can I pass an object CustomListDataAdaptor from doInBackground to onPostExecute?? what is the syntax? thanks a million

Comment: As an asynctask should be an inner class of your main class, simply declare the CustomListDataAdapter as a field of your main class.

Comment: Just figured it out. thanks a lot!!!! Last one how to pass a string (my sql query) as a parametr to doInbackground?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to tell Android to run it on the main UI thread. No need to create a Handler.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```